# Magento Connection timed out

Tags: php, magento, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am having an issue with a Magento migration, I was developing a theme and uploading some products, everything works normal.

The problem is when I try to move the ecosystem from dev to prod, I cloned an Amazon EC2 Instance and an Amazon RDS db, then in the prod instance I point the database to the prod instance and it stops working. I change the db details on `app/etc/local.xml`, I removed cache and session, and it keeps showing

```
    a:4:{i:0;s:43:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out";i:1;s:2493:"#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
    #1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
    #2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
    #3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
    #4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
    #5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
    #6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
    #7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
    #8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
    #9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
    #10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
    #11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
    #12 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
    #13 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1202): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
    #14 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
    #15 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
    #16 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
    #17 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
    #18 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #19 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Everything works normal with the prod instance pointing to dev db instance

PROD Bitnami is a copy of DEV Bitnami
PROD RDS DB  is a restored snapshot of DEV RDS DB

Comment: What are the security group permissions on each of the RDS instances? Is it possible that your prod security group doesn't allow access on port 3306 from the EC2 instance? Have you tested the connection manually from the EC2 instance's command line, e.g. `mysql -h rds.endpoint.com -u user -pPASSWORD`

Comment: I can connect to both instances perfectly from MySQL workbench

Comment: I assume that means from your local computer, not from the EC2 instance? It's likely to be an issue with your security group settings more than anything else.

Comment: You both were all right, it was a security group problem, I guess I should close the answer then, since is not productive, have a nice day

Comment: I am having same issue but sometime approx 5 time in a day